# DataFormWebPart ViewFlag property

Tags: web-part, aspx

In the SP system I'm maintaining I have an aspx page that contains a DataFormWebPart on it. I wanted to make some wording changes in a javascript alert on the page with no real functional changes. I made a copy of it, made my changes, compared the original and copy and noticed that the "ViewFlag" property was changed from "8" in the original to "1048584". The copy I made still has the value "8".

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="My Forms" ViewFlag="1048584"... />
```

My google-fu (or bing-fu in my case) must be weak because I can't find what the property "ViewFlag" property means/represents/does or what any of the values themselves (8, 1048584, etc.) mean. Is there documentation on this somewhere?

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataFormWebPart.ViewFlags property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.viewflags) gets or sets the type of content to be displayed by the DataFormWebPart. The [DataFormWebPart.ViewFlags property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.viewflags) return type is [SPViewFlags enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewflags.aspx) that describes the view type of a Web Part:

```
[System.Flags]
[SubsetCallableType]
public enum SPViewFlags : long
{
   None = 0L,
   Html = 1L,
   ClientModified = 2L,
   TabularView = 4L,
   Hidden = 8L,
   LockWeb = 16L,
   ReadOnly = 32L,
   FailIfEmpty = 64L,
   FreeForm = 128L,
   FileDialog = 256L,
   FileDialogTemplates = 512L,
   AggregationView = 1024L,
   Grid = 2048L,
   Recursive = 4096L,
   RecurrenceRowset = 8192L,
   Contributor = 16384L,
   Moderator = 32768L,
   Threaded = 65536L,
   Chart = 131072L,
   Personal = 262144L,
   Calendar = 524288L,
   Default = 1048576L,
   FilesOnly = 2097152L,
   Ordered = 4194304L,
   Mobile = 8388608L,
   DefaultMobile = 16777216L,
   IncludeVersions = 33554432L,
   Gantt = 67108864L,
   IncludeRootFolder = 134217728L,
   DefaultViewForContentType = 268435456L,
   HideUnapproved = 536870912L,
   RequiresClientIntegration = 1073741824L,
   Unknown = 2147483648L,
}
```

### How to determine what value `DataFormWebPart.ViewFlag` property represents?

You could use the following example to convert the `DataFormWebPart.ViewFlags` value into user-friendly format:

```
const long flagValue = 1048584L;
foreach (long value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SPViewFlags)))
{
    if ((flagValue & value) != 0)
    {
        var flagName = Enum.GetName(typeof (SPViewFlags), value);
        Console.WriteLine(flagName);
    }            
}
```

Result

[image]